# String Serialization in .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently performing a secure code review of Fortify reported issues and segments of code flagged relates to current session state being stored in memory. By default, the framework .NET automatically stores all HttpSessionState objects, its attributes and any object they reference in memory. This implementation limits active session state to what can be accommodated by the system memory of a single machine.

In order to improve performance, it is recommended to mark all objects serializable to expand capacity.

While all steps have been taken to make all these objects Serializable, the fortify scanning tool still flags some string variable as vulnerable.

My question is: Are string variables not serialized by default? or I need explicitly mark these variables "Serializable"?

Comment: Performance has nothing to do with *security*. Saying that some strings are flaged as vulnerable is extremely vague - a "Hello customer!" string isn't vulnerable. A cleartext password is. Making an object serializable has nothing to do with capacity.

Comment: You seem to be eluding the question. The question was "if string variables are serialized by default in .NET.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: If data is not properly stored in memory, it can lead to resource exhaustion which can potentially affect performance and thus a Denial of Service.

Comment: What is the vulnerability category and subcategory? Can you link to it on [vulncat](https://vulncat.hpefod.com/en/weakness)?
Can you share any snippets of code which are being flagged?

Comment: The vulnerability category is: ASP.NET Bad Practices: Non-Serializable Object Stored in Session. The snippets of code flagged is:                                       public partial class CurrentBooking : Page
    {
        private string _s;

        protected void Page_Load(object receiver, EventArgs e)
        {
            _s = Request.QueryString["bookingid"];
            Session[GlobalConstants.GroupGIBR] = _s;
        }
    }

Comment: @user3112342 the question doesn't make any sense. There's no `If data is not properly stored in memory`. There's no `if string variables are serialized by default in .NET`. The `Serializable` attribute doesn't affect how an object's layout in memory. It specifies that a class/struct can be serialized using [Basic serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/basic-serialization). Strings, like other primitive types are serializable

Comment: @user3112342 you mistake what that bad practice is about. It's *not* a vulnerability. *Session state* can be stored in memory only for single server web sites. Once you have two or more servers with load balancing, the state has to be stored in a shared resource like a SQL Server database or Redis cache. To do so, it has to be serialized. That's why either the `Serializable` attribute or implementing [ISerializable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/custom-serialization) is needed.

Comment: @andersonshatch - The vulnerability category is: ASP.NET Bad Practices: Non-Serializable Object Stored in Session. The snippets of code flagged is: public partial class CurrentBooking : Page { private string _s; protected void Page_Load(object receiver, EventArgs e) { _s = Request.QueryString["bookingid"]; Session[GlobalConstants.GroupGIBR] = _s; } }

Answer (score 9):

It's a false-positive detection. String type does not implement ISerializable which (I think) is the reason why Fortify complains. But String is decorated with the [Serializable] attribute as can be seen here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string
and typeof(string).IsSerializable returns true, which gives you enough evidence to request an exemption. Hope it helps.